# Regex returning weird arrays

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to make an array of results from a string like this one, using a regular expression:

```
results|foofoofoo\nresults|barbarbarbar\nresults|googoogoo\ntimestamps||friday
```

Here’s my regex as it stands. It works in Sublime Text’s regex search but not in Ruby:

```
(results)\|.*?\\n(?=((results\|)|(timestamps\|\|)))
```

and this would be the desired result:

```
1. results|foofoofoo
2. results|barbarbar
3. results|googoogoo
```

Instead I’m getting these weird returns, and I can’t understand it. Why does this not select the result lines?

```
Match 1
1. results
2. results|
3. results|
4.  

Match 2
1. results
2. results|
3. results|
4.   

Match 3
1. results
2. timestamps||
3.  
4. timestamps||
```

Here’s the actual code using the regex:

```
#create new lines for each regex'd line body with that body set as the raw attribute
host_scan.raw.scan(/(?:results)\|.*?\\n(?=((?:results\|)|(?:timestamps\|\|)))/).each do |body|
  @lines << Line.new({:raw => body})
end
```

Comment: First: What does the code look like? Second: Why do you have a \\n (\n) in there? There is no \n in your string. (Neither is there a newline.)

Comment: Why use a regex when the more obvious choice is to use `split("\n")` and then use array slices or individual array indexes?

Comment: @theTinMan There are some complications. As far as \n is concerned, for example, there are lots more \n instances in each "result". I feel I'm very close to doing this the "right" way with this regex, it's just not returning the same way it does in Sublime Text.

Comment: If your example is too simple we can't help you very well. It has to be accurate enough to give us a feel for the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry, I've provided the relevant code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to lie in the parentheses. Wrapping in parentheses caused it to return the entire match instead of just the tail delimiter.

```
host_scan.raw.scan(/((?:results\|.*?\\n)(?=(?:results\|)|(?:timestamps\|\|)))/).each do |body|
      @lines << Line.new({:raw => body})
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Kendall Frey already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759477/990363), you are creating too many capture groups. No need to group the first literal “results|”, and no need to group the elements of your alternate group in individual non backreferencing groups. What you are intending to do is this regex:

```
/results\|.*?(?=\\n(?:results\||timestamps\|\|))/
```

or, if you don’t mind repeating the `\\n` part, you can do away with the non-capturing subgroup:

```
/results\|.*?(?=\\nresults\||\\ntimestamps\|\|)/
```

– both will return an array of matched values as specified in your question.

Comment: Also note that this won’t match a “results|foobargoo” string at the end of your line. If you need that one too, the regex is `/results\|.*?(?=\\n(?:results\||timestamps\|\|)|$)/` (or `/results\|.*?(?=\\nresults\||\\ntimestamps\|\||$)/` if you go with the second variant).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has something to do with capturing groups. If you change all your `(...)` to `(?:...)` it will eliminate capturing groups.

Comment: ok that got me a little closer. (?:results)\|.*?\\n(?=((?:results\|)|(?:timestamps\|\|))) returns three matches, although they are only the endings of each group (results| results| and timestamps||)

Comment: Thanks. When I put that one in, though, I get no matches at all.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm starting to think I understand what (?:...) does. It seems to be returning the last appearance of it as the match, because all my matches are results| or timestamps||. Is this correct?

Comment: No, it just specifies a non-capturing group.

Comment: code posted. Thanks for putting up with my inexperience here, I'm still learning the etiquette.

Comment: I can't understand Ruby, sorry. But most regex engines return the full match as the first element in an array, followed by captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than jump to a regex, which is a much more complicated way to get at the data, use `split("\n")`.

```
text = "results|foofoofoo\nresults|barbarbarbar\nresults|googoogoo\ntimestamps||friday"
ary = text.split("\n")
```

`ary` is:

```
[
  "results|foofoofoo",
  "results|barbarbarbar",
  "results|googoogoo",
  "timestamps||friday"
]
```

Slice that and you can get:

```
ary[0..2]
=> ["results|foofoofoo", "results|barbarbarbar", "results|googoogoo"]
```

---

EDIT:

Based on the comment that there are more carriage returns and complex characters in the strings:

```
require 'awesome_print'

text = "results|foofoofoo\nmorefoo\nandevenmorefoo\nresults|barbarbarbar\nandmorebar\nandyetagainmorebar\nresults|googoogoo\ntimestamps||friday"
ap text.sub(/\|\|friday$/, '').split('results')[1..-1].map{ |l| 'results' << l }
```

Which outputs:

```
[
  [0] "results|foofoofoo\nmorefoo\nandevenmorefoo\n",
  [1] "results|barbarbarbar\nandmorebar\nandyetagainmorebar\n",
  [2] "results|googoogoo\ntimestamps"
]
```

Comment: I couldn't put the actual string in here for security reasons (they're vulnerability scans), but split("\n") won't work because the portions I'm trying to select contain \n, not to mention a lot of other stuff. Sorry that I didn't specify that. Your solution would be an elegant one if not for that.

Comment: Something more complex than what's in the added sample above?

Comment: Yes, I have paragraphs of unpredictable text, sometimes containing the words results, |, or \n. This method of dividing it appears to be the only way that will work, I just have to figure out how to get all the text back instead of those strange partial returns.

Comment: By providing some reasonable facsimiles of the data you are working on we can do a lot better job of providing answers. You can cleanse the data of anything that would be sensitive easily enough, just provide samples of the sort of "unpredictable text" you encounter.